# How to clear only one value from text field in one press on button in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I want to clear only one value per press from text field

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

       String s= textfield.getText();
       textfield.setText(s[s.length()-1]);
```

Comment: You want `s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace the entire string each time.

Instead you can update the `Document` directly to only remove the last character:

```
try
{
    Document doc = textField.getDocument();
    doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
}
catch(BadLocationException ble) { ble.getStackTrace(); }
```